# Automated naming of samples in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to automate the numbering and naming of my samples in Access based on the date and the initials of the researcher plus an counter that counts up to 99 for all the samples that have the same beginning.

For example, Michael Jackson produced today the following samples:

MJ2017040401

MJ2017040402... and so on. In the format [initials]YYYYMMDDXX

I got the name of the researcher and the date on the same table where I want to store all the sample information. I tried something like:

Calculated field = [Initials] & str(DatePart("yyyy";[DateProduced])) & str(DatePart["mm";[DateProduced])) & str(DatePart["dd";[DateProduced]))

However, I also don't know how to add an automated counter to that.

Please help :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add a `DCOUNT` with associated parameters to sort that part, presumably on initials?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the counter, you could just a full timestamp. Much faster and easier:

```
Calculated field = [Initials] & Format([DateProduced];"yyyymmddhhnnss")
```

Comment: if I try that, access gives me the error message: `The expression Format([DateProduced];"yyyymmdd") cannot be used in a calculated column`

I added that expression directly in the design view, general>Expression field of the table.

Comment: No, calculated fields are quite limited and also a dead end. Create and use a straight _select query_ where you use the expression as source for a field.